# Changing the height, width of moderncv type resume

Tags: moderncv, geometry, cv

I am trying to change the pagewidth and pagelength of a `moderncv` type CV that can be found here (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv) by changing the values inside inside `moderncv.cls`:

```
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{
  \setlength\paperheight{607mm}
  \setlength\paperwidth{210mm}}
```

But, nothing really changes when I alter the values. Any ideas?

Comment: I am pretty sure, you mean `moderncv.cls`. Anyways, it is not a good idea to patch released classes. Your options are to create a new class with a new name or just put the length declarations into your preamble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't. As the [`moderncv` examples](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples) load [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), so should you, and change the settings using the package interface:

```
\usepackage{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\geometry{paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=607mm}
```